# Map a parameter to output column in a OLEDB Destination?

Tags: ssis

I'm taking an Excel source, and loading it to an OLEDB destination.  The destination needs one more column than the source, and that column needs to be a unique string value which I have stored as a parameter in my project.

```
INPUT COLUMNNS:
ColA
ColB
ColC

OUTPUT COLUMNS:
ColA
ColB
ColC
ColD
```

I want the value of `$Package::MyStringParameter` to fill ColD on every row.  How can I achieve this?

So my OLE DB destination mapping would be kinda like this:

```
OUT:ColA = IN:ColA
OUT:ColB = IN:ColB
OUT:ColC = IN:ColC
OUT:ColD = $Package::MyStringParameter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a script component and make it as a source. That's the only safe bet to append the ColD to each and every row of your source. There are no built-in transformations that can do this automatically for you.

Thanks,

RV

Comment: Actually that seems like a pretty decent solution.. will do, thanks.